How does Playit.gg allow you to host game servers without Port Forwarding?
Back in the day when it came to setting up a Minecraft server on your own local device you needed to go through the process of port forwarding to make your local device accessible from outside your LAN.
At the time this seemed like magic, however I now know this is because entries are added to the NAT Table upon exiting to the WAN, so if one wanted to make it so that others could connect you would need to manually add an entry to the NAT Table pre-emptively.
Nowadays the youngins have playit.gg which is a program that "creates a tunnel so that you can connect your local devices to your friends without the need for port forwarding".
From this I understand that they set up an intermediary pass through service that both the server and friends connect to. This bypasses the need to port forward as since the server will be connected to the pass through service, an entry will be added to the NAT Table.
My question is just making sure that my understanding is correct? Or am I misunderstanding something.

The same way any proxy works without port forwarding.

this is an example of "reverse-tunneling" where software inside your network makes a long-running connection from your network to a cloud endpoint. that's how it bypasses NAT; because the connection initiates from inside your network. cllients can then connect to the cloud endpoint in order to communicate with the service in your LAN that initiated the connection.

@FrankThomas ty for answering my question :)
